# inverse Cayley transformation of product of two Cayley transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let two skew-symmetric matrices $A$, $B$ be given.
We can apply the Cayley transformation $A\mapsto (I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ to get orthogonal matrices which do not have an eigenvalue $=-1$.

Let $\tilde{A}:=(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}$ and $\tilde{B}:=(I-B)(I+B)^{-1}$ the Cayley transformations. Now, the matrix product $\tilde{A}\tilde{B}$ is again orthogonal and does not have an eigenvalue $-1$. So, there is a skew-symmetric matrix $C$ which fulfills $\tilde{A}\tilde{B}=(I-C)(I+C)^{-1}$. Is there a simple formula for $C$ in dependence of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: *“...the matrix product $\tilde{A}\tilde{B}$ is again orthogonal and does not have an eigenvalue $-1$”.* Why not? Consider $\tilde{A}=\tilde{B}=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&0}$ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user1551, I was too sloppy here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes! In fact, the inverse of Cayley transformation is itself a kind of Cayley transformation, and it turns out that

$$C = (I+\tilde{A}\tilde{B})^{-1}(I-\tilde{A}\tilde{B})$$

---

It's easy enough to prove this, so I'll write down the proof here. Let's start from the initial statement that

$$\tilde{A}\tilde{B}=(I-C)(I+C)^{-1}$$

From here, we can obtain $C$ using some algebraic manipulation.

$$\begin{align*}
\tilde{A}\tilde{B}&=(I-C)(I+C)^{-1}\\
\tilde{A}\tilde{B}(I+C)&=I-C\\
\tilde{A}\tilde{B}+\tilde{A}\tilde{B}C&=I-C\\
\tilde{A}\tilde{B}C+C&=I-\tilde{A}\tilde{B}\\
(\tilde{A}\tilde{B}+I)C&=I-\tilde{A}\tilde{B}\\
C&=(I+\tilde{A}\tilde{B})^{-1}(I-\tilde{A}\tilde{B})
\end{align*}$$

---

Or, we can also express $C$ using the initial $A$ and $B$ matrices by using the first formula:

$$\begin{align*}C = &(I+\tilde{A}\tilde{B})^{-1}(I-\tilde{A}\tilde{B}) =\\
= &(I+(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}(I-B)(I+B)^{-1})^{-1}\ \cdot\\ \cdot\ &(I-(I-A)(I+A)^{-1}(I-B)(I+B)^{-1})\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks a lot a very easy and nice proof. A small side note that you are using the condition that $(I+\tilde{A}\tilde{B})$ is invertible since this is not trivially fulfilled as I thought at first

Comment: can the last term be further simplified? I think $(I-A)$ and $(I-A)^{-1}$ are commutative but this does not get us any further, does it?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't reduce the final result further. It is possible that it has a nicer form though.